# Calling a WCF service from client app receives EndpointNotFoundException, but does not error on browser

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I have a newly created WCF .SVC that is hosted in an ASP.NET website that also hosts traditional ASMX-style services.

If I call the single method that is contained in the SVC, I get the following message.

*"There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost/REDACTEDSITE/LicenseVerification.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."*

However, I can paste that link into any browser on my local machine and get the "**This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service. Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.**" page.

The IIS logs show that the browsers are issuing GET requests and receiving a 200 response. The WCF clients are issuing POST requests and receiving 404.0 responses.

These are the latest config settings I have used. They are somewhat minimal.

**host**

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <client entries for other services that work>

    <services>
      <service name="LicenseVerification.svc">
        <endpoint address="LicenseVerification.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Management.ILicenseVerification" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

**client**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/REDACTEDSITE/LicenseVerification.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Management.ILicenseVerification"
          name="LicenseVerificationClient">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**contract**

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILicenseVerification
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method="GET")] //have tried WebGet()
        [OperationContract]
        LicenseInfo GetProfileLicenseInfo(string profileName);
    }
```

**service impl**

```
  public class LicenseVerification : ILicenseVerification
    {
        LicenseInfo ILicenseVerification.GetProfileLicenseInfo(string profileName)
        {
            ProfileInfo _pi = ProfileHelper.GetRequestedProfileInfo(profileName);
            if (_pi == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return LicenseVerifier.GetLicenseInfo(_pi);
        }
    }
```

I have tried re-registering asp.net 4.0, repairing the service model, restarting IIS, trashing and recreating the config files using the MS service config utility and by hand and I still cannot get this to work.

These are small requests (a few KB), so I don't think its a size problem.

The only thing that sticks out is the GET/POST, but that hasn't been a problem before for SVC's that I have made.

My local environment is Win7/64, VS2010, .NET 4.

Please let me know what else to try. I have culled the various SO posts on the same and had no luck (even the ones that look blatantly different).

Comment: Have you tried "[WebInvoke(Method="POST")]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following carlosfigueira's advice and dropping the [web*] attributes and fixing the name of the service in the config, I was able to get a proper service help page but this was still not working from clients.

However, I was now able to use the svcutil to generate the code and config that my service required. What I found from that generated output.config file was that the endpoint address was duplicated at the end, like this...

```
http://localhost/REDACTEDSITE/LicenseVerification.svc/LicenseVerification.svc
```

This is the endpoint that the client needed to hit in order to consume the service, and when I updated the clients config to hit that endpoint, it WORKED!

This was still not optimal, so I tried removing the address element from my service config so that it now looks like this (sans behavior confg).

```
  <service name="Management.LicenseVerification">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Management.ILicenseVerification" />
  </service>
```

And it still works!

I am somewhat confused as to why this would append the address element, other than maybe its a side effect of hosting this in asp.net. Perhaps address elements (and base address) do not need to be configured in this case?

In any event, this is now working.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the "name" property of the `<service>` element in the server's config is incorrect. It should list the **fully-qualified name of the service class** (probably `Management.LicenseVerification`), and not the name of the .svc file.

A few more issues:

- You're using `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]` in your operation. Use `[WebGet]` instead if you want it to be accessed via GET
- [WebInvoke] (and [WebGet]) are only honored for endpoints which use the `webHttpBinding` and have an endpoint behavior with `<webHttp/>`, none of those you have (you're using `basicHttpBinding`).
- The browser is sending a GET request, but it's not invoking the operation, it's probably getting the service help page. So it's probably not really "working" from the browser.

Comment: While these did not actually correct the problem, they did lead me to getting a working solution, so thank you @carlosfigueria!